# Apply second mean-value theorem for integrals on $\int\limits_x^{1/2}\frac{\sin((2M+1)\pi t)}{\sin \pi t}\mathrm{d}t$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, analytic-number-theory

In a textbook on analytic numbertheory we want to prove that
\begin{equation}
\Big\vert \{a\}-\frac{1}{2}-\sum\limits_{\substack{\vert m\vert\leq M \\ m\not=0}}\frac{\exp(-2\pi im\alpha)}{2\pi im}\Big\vert\leq\frac{1}{2\pi M\Vert \alpha\Vert}
\end{equation}

In the prove we rewrite some stuff and end up with the following integral we want to estimate:

$$\int\limits_\alpha^{1/2}\frac{\sin((2M+1)\pi t)}{\sin \pi t}\mathrm{d}t$$

with $0<\alpha\leq 1/2$. The author claims that the second mean-value theorem gives us

$$\frac{1}{\sin(\pi \alpha)}\int\limits_\alpha^\xi \sin((2M+1)\pi t) \mathrm{d}t$$ with $\xi\in(\alpha,1/2)$ and that this is trivally bounded by  $$\frac{1}{2\pi M\Vert \alpha\Vert}$$
First, I am not sure how we end up with this above integral using the second mean-value theorem.
I found two versions of it here  [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorems_for_definite_integrals), but in the first version we would have $\xi\in(\alpha,1/2]$, and in the second one I do not see how the second term vanishes.

Also, I do not see how this would be trivally bounded by the aboves term. Here $\Vert\alpha\Vert$ is supposed to be the distance from $\alpha$ to the nearest integer, but I don't see how this appears.

I would really appreciate any hints on this!

Comment: $\sin(\pi t)$ is not a constant function, so when $\alpha<\frac12$, $\xi$ cannot be $\frac12$.

Comment: perhaps he (i think i recognise bruedern's book?) maybe meant $\in (\alpha ,1/2]$, it doesn't make a difference.  the next thing you do is integrate and this gives you the $1/M$ term.  and then you bound $sin(\pi \alpha )\gg \alpha =||\alpha ||$